How do we separate django project into multiple docker containers
I have a django project right now that allows users to login and register an account. Sort of like a blog. All the views are separated and have their own static html file. The project works running locally and all.
Users data is currently running with the default sqlite3 database
currently i am able to put the whole project into a single docker container and it works when I run it.
I use commands:
docker compose up --build
I am trying to separate my docker project into multiple docker containers.
I want separate containers for the frontend and backend.
a lot of tutorials online show how to have multiple containers using only postgressql, but I couldn't find much on sqlite3(django default database). I want to be able to do this with a sqlite3. Is this a way to do this.
I have a requirements file, .dockerignore, Dockerfile, and a docker-compose.yml file.
Any help would be appreciated.
docker-compose.yml:
eversion: "3"

services:
django:
    image: django-docker:0.0.1
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"```


Dockerfile:

FROM python:3.12.3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFER=1

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py","runserver"]


The Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml are in two separate files. Mistake when adding code blocks.

What are you hoping to gain by running multiple containers?  SQLite doesn't have a dedicated database server and can't run in a separate container; conversely, maintaining a single SQLite file can be a problem in a container environment, and it's often a better practice to have a separate database container, maybe using PostgreSQL or another standard relational database.  If your application otherwise runs as a single process (your application serves its own frontend code as static assets) then you don't really need a "frontend container".

Thank for your input. I was on the fence whether on not to migrate my data over to a PostgresSQL database. Would changing the database mess with my currently working code. They are both sql based so i m not sure if they are compatable or not.

There are minor differences between relational databases, to be sure.  If you're mostly leaning on an ORM like SQLAlchemy, though, you're unlikely to see those.  Do you have any direct SQL statements in your code, and are they more complex than simple INSERT, DELETE, and SELECT?

No I do not. The only code I had before that would interact with sqlite3 was .save to add things to the database and  then I would use django's default authentication.
